# Need more coordinates from CLGeocoder than the limit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit, clgeocoder

following code is returning me coordinates only for first **10 addresses**. But i need more than 100 to store that in a database. is there a limit of geocoder? how can i do it ?

```
 for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
{

    CLGeocoder *geoCode = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    [geoCode geocodeAddressString:strcity completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error)
         {
             CLPlacemark *place = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
             CLLocation *location = place.location;
             CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = location.coordinate;

             NSString *tempLati=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%g",coord.latitude];
             NSString *tempLongi=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%g",coord.longitude];




             [objCountries.countryLatitude addObject:tempLati];
             [objCountries.countryLongitude addObject:tempLongi];

             [geoCode cancelGeocode];
         }
     }];


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS throttles CLGeocoder requests, it varies but generally allows 50 or so requests at a time.  The time period is an unknown.  What you can do is code it to geocode a chunk at a time, leaving an adequate pause in between.  Wherever possible once read you should store the result so you don't request the same geocode again.  Take note of the CLGeocoder documentation here : [CLGeocoder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html) .  Apple can restrict you or even suspend your developer account if the gecoding services are abused.

Comment: ok. Thanks a lot. do you know how to set delay time betweeen request of geocode. are there any method that calls when geocode response?

Comment: I think maybe using an NSTimer would be good - you could use the repeat option to geocode a number at a time with a short delay between, then invalidate the NSTimer once all locations have been geocoded.  There's lots of examples of NSTimer on SO.